# Hosting on different platforms

Tags: wordpress, shopify, web-hosting

I am hosting a store on Shopify which runs an ecommerce store, I am also making a marketplace on Wordpress which is hosted on AWS. I own the domain on go daddy.com

Here are my questions:
mydomain.com currently points to Shopify store
I want to send my users from Shopify store to Wordpress marketplace via the menu for.e.g mydomain.com/marketplace should goto marketplace.mydomain.com(hosted on Wordpress)

What all things I need to do to achieve this?
Create a sub domain on go daddy? and point it to where?
reconfigure DNS on wordpress hosting service?

Comment: You can just set up a subdomain through godaddy and then [configure it to redirect to your wordpress site](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-forward-or-mask-your-domain-or-subdomain-422). You can mask it if you don't want it to show the AWS url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you need to create the subdomain in godaddy.com and then you need to write the set of code in vhost file at AWS. vHost file depends on operating system you are using in AWS. Sample vhost file :

```
<VirtualHost 172.20.30.50> # ip to be replace by your ip
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/yoursite"
    ServerName marketplace.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will help